# How to set the sessions in .aspx according to the rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, eval

I face the following problem :

when I set my sessions in my aspx according to my requirements like this :

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10px">
<ItemTemplate>
<a id="btnShowPopup5" runat="server" class="thickbox" href='<%#"PopUp.aspx?AR=2"+"&TBiframe=true&height=530&width=750"%>'
<asp:Image ID="Image23" runat="server" ToolTip="Back" ImageUrl="Images/cross.png" /></a>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HDN_TaskCode" Value='<%# Session["s_TaskCode"] = DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TaskCode") %>'
runat="server" />
```

---

I note that : `Session["s_TaskCode"]` was set always with the first row task code value in the gridview!!

and this's not what i want.

I want to set my sessions according to the rows .

say my gridview has two rows :

- The first task_code value is 7
- The second task_code value is 10

I want to set the session with the correct value according to the hyper link i click on .

Like data keys.

**Note** : i want to set my sessions in the .aspx not .cs .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have using only one Session Variable (`Session["s_TaskCode"]`) in your code. So, how can you retain multiple values in it. It will always contain the value last written to it.

To store row-wise values in session, you have to do something like:

`Session["s_TaskCode" + rowIndex]`

Here, rowIndex is <%# Container.DataItemIndex %>

So you can use like: `<%# Session["s_TaskCode" + Container.DataItemIndex] %>`

**Edit:**

Instead of session, why don't you pass the value of TaskCode in the 'btnShowPopup5' href url QueryString parameters:

```
href='<%#"PopUp.aspx?AR=2"+"&TBiframe=true&height=530&width=750&" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TaskCode") %>'
```

Comment: Then with this way I will set the session with the first row value also plus the row index !!

Comment: yes, but you can always check if rowIndex = 0 then use Session["s_TaskCode"].

Comment: also i get compile error `The name 'rowIndex' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: no i want to set the session with the correct value according to the link click. cuz i use this value later

Comment: <%# Container.DataItemIndex %> will give you rowIndex.

Comment: Could u update in my code `Value='<%# Session["s_TaskCode"] = DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TaskCode") %>'`

Comment: I used the query string ,and then i find those data have to be more secure so i have to use sessions instead. and because we used `Thickbox` jquery i should use this method of setting the sessions in the `.aspx`

Comment: @just_name you can encode the sensitive data before passing it to QueryString.